# string.replace() cannot replace char " \" "

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have below `json` from request post in my `MVC` model

```
"{\"Brand\":\"\",\"Name\":\"apotik AA\",\"Desc\":\"\",\"Address\":\"Address\",\"Phone\":\"\",\"Tag\":\"\",\"City\":\"BEKASI\",\"Status\":\"0\"}
```

I don't know why the `json` object filled with `(\")` instead only `(")` but when I check the value with `allert` in `html`, it not content `(\")`

So I want to replace `(/")` with `(")`

```
[Authorization()]
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Update(VModel vModel)
{
   string JsonArray = (vModel.JsonVar).Replace('\"',' ');
}
```

but result still

```
"{\"Brand\":\"\",\"Name\":\"apotik AA\",\"Desc\":\"\",\"Address\":\"Address\",\"Phone\":\"\",\"Tag\":\"\",\"City\":\"BEKASI\",\"Status\":\"0\"}
```

how can?

Comment: If you're looking at that string in the debugger it isn't filled with `\"`. That is just how VS displays it's strings when it needs to escape characters. Use a Trace.WriteLine to be sure.

Comment: Replace(@"\",' ');

Comment: hooo, so what should i do?, i used json.stringify in my javascript

Comment: @h__ what do you mean?

Comment: The @ operator uses the written string explicitly without need of using escape characters.

Comment: The string doesn't contain any backslash characters. The string *does* contain double-quote characters, which are also the characters that C# uses to denote the start and end of string literals. So, if you wanted to type that string into some C# source file, you'd use backslashes to escape the double-quotes that are actually part of the string. Whatever original problem you were looking at which sent you down this blind alley, trying to "remove" the backslashes isn't going to solve it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hoo i see, so what should i do?

Comment: I don't know - your entire question is focussed on the phantom issue of the backslash characters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've mistaken VS debugger output with the real string. Try to open the actual string in the debugger (press loupe).
But if you actually need to replace \" with " use this code:

```
string JsonArray = JsonVar.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Or you can just delete all slashes with

```
string JsonArray = JsonVar.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class model
{
    public static string jsonVar { get; set; }
}

   public static string ReplaceStringChars(string str)
    {
        string newStr = string.Empty;

        newStr = str.Replace('\"' , ' ');

        return newStr;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        model.jsonVar = "{\"Brand\":\"\",\"Name\":\"apotik AA\",\"Desc\":\"\",\"Address\":\"Address\",\"Phone\":\"\",\"Tag\":\"\",\"City\":\"BEKASI\",\"Status\":\"0\"}";
        ReplaceStringChars(model.jsonVar);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `string newStr = string.Empty;` - you do not need to "initialize" the string as it's already declared as a string and will be (re-)assigned in the next line.

Comment: @Hans Kesting yes u r right, I forgot to correct that.